# Embedding HornetQ in Spring

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

I am trying to evaluate HornetQ and the possibility of embedding it in a spring application. To start with a simple setup I am just trying to initialize it as follows. I didn't find much documentation about how to do this, apart from the fact that 'you can'.

I am using Spring 3 and HornetQ 2.1.1GA

My Spring configuration looks like this, however if theres a simpler cleaner configuration it would be better. I want the minimalistic approach first and then build on it.:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


<bean name="mbeanServer" class="java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" factory-method="getPlatformMBeanServer" />

<bean name="fileConfiguration" class="org.hornetq.core.config.impl.FileConfiguration" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" />

<bean name="hornetQSecurityManagerImpl" class="org.hornetq.spi.core.security.HornetQSecurityManagerImpl" />

<!-- The core server -->
<bean name="hornetQServerImpl" class="org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl">
 <constructor-arg ref="fileConfiguration" />
 <constructor-arg ref="mbeanServer" />
 <constructor-arg ref="hornetQSecurityManagerImpl" />
</bean>

<!-- The JMS server -->
<bean name="jmsServerManagerImpl" class="org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" >
 <constructor-arg ref="hornetQServerImpl" />
</bean>

    <bean name="connectionFactory" class="org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory" >
 <constructor-arg>
  <bean class="org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration">
   <constructor-arg value="org.hornetq.integration.transports.netty.NettyConnectorFactory" />
   <constructor-arg>
    <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Object">
     <entry key="port" value="5445"></entry>
    </map>
   </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
 </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean name="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
 <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

With this config I am getting the error:

```
SEVERE: Unable to deploy node [queue: null] DLQ
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
...
29-Dec-2010 18:16:34 org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate error
SEVERE: Unable to deploy node [queue: null] ExpiryQueue
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
...
9-Dec-2010 18:16:34 org.hornetq.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate error
SEVERE: Unable to deploy node [queue: null] ExampleQueue
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
```

Its must be something obvious related to JNDI, but I would appreciate the proper minimalistic configuration to start with and then expand on it afterwards. The HornetQ configuration files are the default ones that come with the distribution (default queues, default users etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the JMS queues you want to add to the server, and specify an empty list of JNDI bindings for each queue. To do this, add a JMSConfigurationImpl to your JMSServerManagerImpl bean definition. For example, if you need to define a queue called "testqueue":

```
  <bean id="hornetQJmsConfig" class="org.hornetq.jms.server.config.impl.JMSConfigurationImpl">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
      <list/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <!-- Queue configurations -->
    <constructor-arg index="1">
      <list>
        <bean class="org.hornetq.jms.server.config.impl.JMSQueueConfigurationImpl">
          <!-- Name -->
          <constructor-arg index="0" value="testqueue"/>
          <!-- Selector -->
          <constructor-arg index="1"><null/></constructor-arg>
          <!-- Durable queue -->
          <constructor-arg index="2" value="true"/>
          <!-- JNDI bindings, empty list for none -->
          <constructor-arg index="3"><list/></constructor-arg>
        </bean>
      </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <!-- Topic configurations -->
    <constructor-arg index="2">
      <list/>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

Since the second and third constructor args take a list of queue and topic configurations, you can add as many queues and topics as you like. For more than one or two, it's probably best to create a Spring template object.